# Why only Muslims should go to Jannah why not non muslims?

Tags: non-muslim, jannah

Good deed can be done by non Muslims as well so why only Muslims should go in Jannah.

Comment: Aisha reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Be deliberate in worship, draw near to Allah, and give glad tidings. Verily, none of you will enter Paradise because of his deeds alone.” They said, “Not even you, O Messenger of Allah?” The Prophet said, “Not even me, unless Allah grants me mercy from himself. Know that the most beloved deed to Allah is that which is done regularly even if it is small.” Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 6099, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2818 ...so even Muslims will not to paradise because of their good deeds but will go because of Allah's Mercy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because non-Muslims disbelieve Allah, deny His messengers and revelations, disregard His signs, disobey His commands. So why should they have the same fate as the Muslims who submitted to and obeyed Allah and believed in His messengers and revelations?

https://legacy.quran.com/32/18-22

> Then is one who was a believer like one who was defiantly disobedient?
>   They are not equal.
>
> As for those who believed and did righteous deeds, for them will be
>   the Gardens of Refuge as accommodation for what they used to do.
>
> But as for those who defiantly disobeyed, their refuge is the Fire.
>   Every time they wish to emerge from it, they will be returned to it
>   while it is said to them, "Taste the punishment of the Fire which you
>   used to deny."
>
> And we will surely let them taste the nearer punishment short of the
>   greater punishment that perhaps they will repent.
>
> And who is more unjust than one who is reminded of the verses of his
>   Lord; then he turns away from them? Indeed We, from the criminals,
>   will take retribution.

https://legacy.quran.com/68/35-45:

> Then will We treat the Muslims like the criminals?
>
> What is [the matter] with you? How do you judge?
>
> Or do you have a scripture in which you learn
>
> That indeed for you is whatever you choose?
>
> Or do you have oaths [binding] upon Us, extending until the Day of
>   Resurrection, that indeed for you is whatever you judge?
>
> Ask them which of them, for that [claim], is responsible.
>
> Or do they have partners? Then let them bring their partners, if they
>   should be truthful.
>
> The Day the shin will be uncovered and they are invited to prostration
>   but the disbelievers will not be able,
>
> Their eyes humbled, humiliation will cover them. And they used to be
>   invited to prostration while they were sound.
>
> So leave Me, [O Muhammad], with [the matter of] whoever denies the
>   Qur'an. We will progressively lead them [to punishment] from where
>   they do not know.
>
> And I will give them time. Indeed, My plan is firm.

https://legacy.quran.com/20/126

> [ Allah ] will say, "Thus did Our signs come to you, and you forgot them; and thus will you this Day be forgotten."

https://legacy.quran.com/3/162

> So is one who pursues the pleasure of Allah like one who brings upon himself the anger of Allah and whose refuge is Hell? And wretched is the destination.

Comment: A non-muslim is someone who does not believe Islam, but this does not necessarily mean that he disbelieve in it. For example, A person in doubt is neither a believer nor a disbeliever.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right non Muslim also do good things  and they get their reward in this world. Allah almighty blessed them what they want on the behalf of their good deeds.
But the Muslims are much blessed because they have believed in Allah and his Prophet and the Holy book.
These beliefs make differences between Muslims and non Muslims.
So that's why they go to jannah after their day of judgment